# How to get an error log in Azure AD B2C tenant with correlation ID?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-ad-b2c

I have encountered a problem in creating a custom policy for Azure AD B2C authentication and would like to look in the detail of the server error with a correlation ID.

But, even if I'm logging into the B2C tenant in Powershell via `Connect-AzureAD -[hoge].onmicrosoft.com"`, when I hit `Get-AzureRmLog`, it requires me to login to my Azure account of `[fuga]@outlook.com` (not B2C tenant) and I cannot access the subscription in B2C.

So how can I investigate errors occurred in B2C tenant? Also if there's a way to get it done without Powershell it'd be much better.

**EDIT:**
The error seems occurred when I try signing-in via the custom policy of the tenant. Below is the header showing the error.
[image]

Comment: Hi K. Makino. What is the server error? Is it **500 Internal Server Error**?

Comment: I think its 5xx error but not sure about the detail, because the correlation id of the error is contained in the response from login.microsoft.com when I try signing-in via a custom policy of the tenant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can debug a custom policy by sending the log entries from Azure AD B2C to Azure Application Insights as described by [Azure Active Directory B2C: Collecting Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-troubleshoot-custom).

A log entry contains the correlation identifier.

Note that there is a short delay (less than five minutes) before the log entries are sent.

If you don't want to wait, then you can configure the custom policy with the following settings to send the log entries from Azure AD B2C via an [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) endpoint to your local machine:

```xml
<TrustFrameworkPolicy
    PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0"
    TenantId="***.onmicrosoft.com"
    PolicyId="B2C_1A_***"
    ...
    DeploymentMode="Development"
    UserJourneyRecorderEndpoint="https://***.ngrok.io"
    ... />
```

**UPDATE: 4 April 2019**

Unfortunately, support for sending the log entries to a HTTP endpoint has been deprecated, so you must use Azure Application Insights.

Comment: It does seems to work anymore. I have an error saying that `UserJourneyRecorderEndpoint` can only be `urn:journeyrecorder:applicationinsights`. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Hi @Thomas. No, you aren't missing anything, support for the HTTP endpoint has been deprecated.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPadgett. Good to know. I am having some issue troubleshooting some B2C errors. I am using app insights but logs sent from AAD B2C to app insights are too long and are truncated so most the time, I can't see the underlying error message.